# Stack Overflow "Edit queue full", but the queue isn’t actually full

Tags: discussion

I am trying to edit an answer that is wrong, however when I click submit I get: "The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes!"

However, when I go to check the queue length @ https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats, it is at 432 and in the 10 minutes since it has become 437.

According to the information I have been able to find, the queue length is capped at 500...(?)

Is there a separate cap I haven't found for people with low reputation? Or is there a bug here...?

Comment: Probably caching... https://shouldiblamecaching.com